# EAR best practice with JBoss

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

We are using JBoss 7.1, with an Apache upfront (proxying the requests to the right place).

I need to separate my `EAR` project into several `WARs` (and one `JAR`), because it is becoming too large.

I wonder whether I should use several EARs and duplicate the `JAR`, or use the same `EAR` with several `WARs`.

The second option seems best to me (no duplicate code), but I would like to be able to redeploy only one `WAR`. But when I modify one `WAR` folder inside the `EAR`, the whole `EAR` gets redeployed.

Is that normal? 
What's the best practice for managing several WARs related to the same backend logic (same EJB/JAR).

Thanks!

Comment: The version of JBoss you are using is relevant, please add it to your question.

Comment: right ; that's JBoss 7.1

Comment: I'd say you can create custom modules for every common jar file under `$JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/company/module/main/module.xml`, and take advantage of JBoss 7 classloading as explained [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7).

Comment: actually the `JAR` contains EJB, it should be in /deployments shouldn't it ?

Comment: well, I'm asking an open question, I understand one cannot help me easily. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I think requesting your Q to be migrated to StackOverflow would be beneficial for you.